# Why does each of my sections appear so close together on my mobile devices when I have set up each section to be one page size view?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently on a MacBook with the display dimensions of 15.4-inch (2880 x 1800) here is a screenshot of how each section of my website looks for my homepage.

**`#app` (section1)**

[image]

**`#section2` (section2)**

[image]

**`#section3` (section3)**

[image]

**----------**

**MY ISSUE**

Why does each of my sections appear so close together on my mobile devices when I have set up each section to be one page size view?

I have given them all `ID`'s and have used CSS to make them all one page like also demonstrated in the above screenshots of my MacBook view.

```
#app,
#section2,
#section3 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here is a screenshot to show how close they're on a mobile view which I don't want. I wanted them to have their own page size view like on my above screenshots on my MacBook.

[image]

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wdafatrx/2/)

Comment: You have unclosed divs https://jsfiddle.net/wdafatrx/5/